# Mysql + Eager Loading causes ConstraintException

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I try to load several related entities using eager loading (some simple Include statements). But for some strange reason a ConstraintException is thrown. I am not sure if this is a bug in the MySql Connector or somewhere else.

My schema looks like this: 
[image]

When I try to load the data using this statement:

```
CurrentConnection.DynFormPresetSet
.Include("Definitions")
.Include("Definitions.FieldDefs")
.Include("Definitions.FieldDefs.Literals")
.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PresetValue == (int)presetDefinition);
```

I get this exception:

```
[ConstraintException: Diese Eigenschaft kann nicht auf einen NULL-Wert festgelegt werden.]
System.Data.EntityUtil.ThrowPropertyIsNotNullable(String propertyName) +89
System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.StructuralObject.SetValidValue(String value, Boolean isNullable) +24
MyApp.Model.DynFormLiteral.set_Label(String value) in d:\Dev\CSharp\Repository\MyApp.Model\MyEntities.cs:2900
lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +341
```

The problem is caused by the `Definitions.FieldDefs.Literals` relation. If I remove the eager loading on the Literals it works. I checked the ResultSet produced by the SQL Query and for it looks like the Entity Framework tries to create a DynFormLiteral even if none were assigned. The ID Column responsible for the Literal is not null for some strange reason.

If I include the `Definitions.FieldDefs.Validators` instead of the `Literals` the statement is also working. But if I include the `Literals` and the `Validators` the SQL Statement is totally invalid:

```
[MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'Extent1.Id' in 'where clause']
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +383
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) +116
```

I can't really explain what's happening there but I know it's wrong! Does anybody have encountered similar problems or has an idea how to resolve this problem?

My current setup is:

- MariaDB 5.5.29
- MySQL Connector 6.6.5
- Entity Framework 4
- [Table Per Hierarchy Generation](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87)

Comment: What's at d:\Dev\CSharp\Repository\MyApp.Model\MyEntities.cs line 2900 and what's the column definition for the corresponding database table column?

Comment: The MyEntities.cs is the Entity-Container/Context generated by the T4-File. The Line 2900 is the setter of a primitive Property `Label` (not nullable) of the DynFormLiteral entity. I am using EntityObjects and not Pocos.

Comment: I was able to reduce the problem to a simple solution. It seems it's a problem to use eager loading on an entity if it has a One-To-Many and a Many-To-Many Relation on it. I uploaded a solution showing the problem: [Download Solution](http://www.coderline.net/MySqlBug.rar)

Comment: Another Update. I tried to use the dotConnect provider for MySql and it isn't working there as well. The exception says: [NotSupportedException: OUTER APPLY is not supported by MySQL.]
. It seems this special query which isn't supported by MySQL is being rebuilt in the Oracle MySql Provider, but wrong!

Comment: Btw for updates you can edit your question